# Character Array needs to display in certain order and place

Tags: java, swing, arrays

Trying to get the final part of this game to work. Its a hangman game, I just need it to display correct guesses where they are in the word.

This is the snippet of code of when a correct guess is given

```
else
            {
                int alreadyGuessed = guesses.indexOf(guess);
                if (alreadyGuessed == -1)
                {

                    guesses = guesses + guess + "";
                    jlbWord.setText("Word: " + charWord[currentGuess]);
                }
                else{}

            }
```

Right now it simply shows each letter. I can also set it, so it shows each one as they are typed in but its not in the right order, which makes it much more difficult for the user to guess what the word is.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class RightPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
JLabel jlbMissed, jlbWord, jlbTimer;
Color btnColor;
JComboBox jcbDifficulty;
JButton jbtStart, jbtQuit;
String[] difficulties = {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"};
String[] words = {"First", "Next", "Hello", "World"};
char guess;
String word, guesses = "";
char[] charWord;
public static int incorrectGuesses = 0;
boolean clockIsRunning = false;
boolean gameInPlay = false;
int sec = 0;
int min = 0;



public RightPanel()
{

    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    Random ran = new Random();  //
    int rand = ran.nextInt(4);  // Generates random number then selects word from words array
    word = words[rand];         //
    charWord = word.toCharArray();
    ActionHandler actionHandler = new ActionHandler();
    jlbMissed   = new JLabel("Missed: ");
    jlbWord     = new JLabel("Word: ");
    jlbTimer    = new JLabel("Time: " + "0:00");
    jbtStart    = new JButton("Start");
    jbtQuit     = new JButton("Quit");
    jcbDifficulty = new JComboBox();
    jbtStart.addActionListener(actionHandler);
    jbtQuit.addActionListener(actionHandler);
    jcbDifficulty.addKeyListener(this);
    jbtStart.addKeyListener(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        jcbDifficulty.addItem(difficulties[i]); // Creates Difficutly ComboBox
    }
    this.add(jcbDifficulty, getConstraints(0,0,1,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
    this.add(jlbMissed, getConstraints(0,1,1,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
    this.add(jlbWord, getConstraints(0,2,1,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
    this.add(jlbTimer, getConstraints(0,4,1,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
    this.add(jbtStart, getConstraints(0,6,1,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
    this.add(jbtQuit, getConstraints(0,7,1,1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));




}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
    guess = e.getKeyChar();
    if (gameInPlay == false)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You have not started the game yet!", "Game has not Started", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Game Not in Play");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(guess))
        {

            if (incorrectGuesses > 11)
            {
                clockIsRunning = false;
                gameInPlay = false;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You Killed Him! \nThe word was " + word, "He Ceases to Exist", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                jbtStart.setText("Retry?");
                jbtStart.setBackground(Color.RED);

            }
            else
            {
                int currentGuess = word.indexOf(guess);
                if (currentGuess == -1)
                {
                    int alreadyGuessed = guesses.indexOf(guess);
                    if (alreadyGuessed == -1)
                    {
                        guesses = guesses + guess + "";
                        System.out.println(alreadyGuessed);
                        System.out.println(guesses);
                        String temp = jlbMissed.getText();
                        jlbMissed.setText(temp + guess + ", ");
                        incorrectGuesses++;
                        leftPanel.hangmanPic.setIcon(leftPanel.image[RightPanel.incorrectGuesses]);
                    }
                    else {}
                }
                else
                {
                    int alreadyGuessed = guesses.indexOf(guess);
                    if (alreadyGuessed == -1)
                    {

                        guesses = guesses + guess + "";
                        jlbWord.setText("Word: " + charWord[currentGuess]);
                    }
                    else{}

                }
            }
        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "That is not a valid guess!\n Please enter a character from A-Z", "Invalid Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


    }

}


private GridBagConstraints getConstraints(int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, int anchor)
{
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    c.ipadx = 0;
    c.ipady = 0;
    c.gridx = gridx;
    c.gridy = gridy;
    c.gridwidth = gridwidth;
    c.gridheight = gridheight;
    c.anchor = anchor;
    return c;
}

class ActionHandler implements ActionListener
  {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jbtStart)
    {
        if (clockIsRunning == true){}
        else
        {
            if (jbtStart.getText() == "Start")
            {
                btnColor = jbtStart.getBackground();
                clockIsRunning = true;
                MyTimer timer = new MyTimer();
                timer.start();
                gameInPlay = true;
            }
            else if (jbtStart.getText() == "Retry?")
            {
                jbtStart.setText("Start");
                jbtStart.setBackground(btnColor);
                jlbTimer.setText("Time: " + "0:00");
                sec = 0;
                min = 0;
                MyTimer timer = new MyTimer();
                timer.start();
                clockIsRunning = true;
                gameInPlay = true;
                incorrectGuesses = 0;
                guesses = "";
                jlbMissed.setText("Missed: ");
                jlbWord.setText("Word: ");
                leftPanel.hangmanPic.setIcon(leftPanel.image[RightPanel.incorrectGuesses]);
                Random ran = new Random();
                int rand = ran.nextInt(4);
                word = words[rand];
            }
        }
    }
    else if (source == jbtQuit)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
  }
  class MyTimer extends Thread
  {
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(!clockIsRunning)
            break;
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ecp)
        {
        }

        if (sec == 59)
        {
            min++;
            sec = 0;
        }
        else
            sec++;
        if(sec < 10)
            jlbTimer.setText("Time:" + min+":0"+sec);
        else
            jlbTimer.setText("Time:" + min+":"+sec);
    }
}
  }







}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes.

You *should* refactor your code and keep the guesses in a `TreeSet<Character>` data structure. It assures, that each character is stored only once and that an iterator returns all stored chars in ascending order.

Snippet:

```
 Set<Character> guesses = new HashSet<Character>();

 // add a guess
 guesses.add('e');
 guesses.add('r');
 guesses.add('a');
 guesses.add('e'); // will not be added, already in the set

 // test
 if (guesses.contains('e')) { ... }

 // test if a word is "guessed"
 boolean foundIt = true;
 for (char c:word.toCharArray()) {
    if (!guesses.contains(c)) {
      foundIt = false;
      break;
    }
 }
 // foundIt is true if all chars of word have been guessed

 // print
 for (char c:guesses)
   System.out.print(c);  // prints: aer
```